# Build CMake project with protobuf

Tags: c++, cmake

I try to build this example that shows how to use CMake to manage a C++ project with protobuf.

https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example

But I keep getting this error:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:429 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 2.6.1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  proto/CMakeLists.txt:1 (INCLUDE)
-- Found Protobuf: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread (found version "2.6.1")
```

I do have a protoc binary with version 3.4, and I also have libprotobuf.so in another path. How do I specify CMake to use my libprotobuf.so instead of the one under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`?

Comment: You presented a _warning_, not an error. Does CMake finish successfully after that? If not, please post the full error. If CMake succeeds and the build fails, please post the compiler/linker error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `Protobuf_LIBRARY`, `Protobuf_PROTOC_LIBRARY` and `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR` variables to their proper values using `-D` CMake flag..